# Trouble with mongorestore (don't know what to do with subdirectory)

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I use this cmd to restore mongodb to remote db on mLab

```
$ ./mongorestore -h ds*****.mlab.com:**** -u <user> -p <pass> -d loc8r
```

but I got this error

```
2018-05-01T20:22:18.463+0700    using default 'dump' directory
2018-05-01T20:22:18.463+0700    building a list of collections to restore from dump dir
2018-05-01T20:22:18.464+0700    don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump\Loc8r", skipping...
2018-05-01T20:22:18.464+0700    don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump\admin", skipping...
2018-05-01T20:22:18.464+0700    done
```

I wonder if I did something wrong? there's no problem when I use the same cmd with the dump folder only contains .bson file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `mongorestore` when attempting to restore a backup dump (originally created using `mongodump` utility), the `mongorestore` utility needs to have access to the .bson file.

When you took the backup/dump, if the .bson file did not exist in the Root folder (of your Data folder), then you will have to explicitly specify its path. What I mean is:

Say you took a backup/dump in `D:\mongo_bkup_dir\` folder and if you do have the `.bson` file in the root (where the backup was taken), then just providing the root folder location, e.g.:

```
mongorestore --port 27017 --db dbName --username usr1 --password P@ssw0rd --authenticationDatabase authDbName --dir D:\mongo_bkup_dir\
```

However, if you had `.bson` file in a sub-folder called ***myDir*** (when backup was taken), then use:

```
mongorestore --port 27017 --db dbName --username usr1 --password P@ssw0rd --authenticationDatabase authDbName --dir D:\mongo_bkup_dir\mybackup1.dmp\myDir
```

HTH.